# What's an effective method for contrasting colors between adjacent groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following plot, there are 26 named nodes (the diamonds; names are a-z), each of which is surrounded by a cluster of 4 points (children). My objective is to show how the children cluster around each node- how many children there are (set to 4 in this artificial example), how far away they are from their parent node, and in what direction.

[image]

To this end, it would be helpful if the color contrast between nearby nodes was always large. You can see here that the contrast is in many cases sufficient, but there are problems: Colors for k and l are similar or identical; the same holds for b and c, g and h, etc. Having clusters of similar colors near each other reduces the interpretability of the chart.

It seems to me that there must be a solution to this issue based on something like the [four color theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem). For example, if I could define contiguous regions around each node, I could achieve consistent contrast with as little as four colors.

But, I can't figure out a good approach (without sinking more time than this is ultimately worth to me right now!). This seems like the sort of problem that should have a known solution. Does it?